# what does "replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh" mean?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

very quick newbish question here...
In the jquery-mobile docs, it says that

> Note that the refresh() method only affects new nodes appended to a list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list item, these won't be reflected. **If you want a list item to be updated, replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh**.

What does exactly does the bolded part means, and how to do I get achieving that?
(Probably goes without saying that I don't have a lot of javascript or HTML experience :) )

Answer (score 0):

It means:

You have a list containing data.

if you run refresh() nothing happens.

if you append new data to the list (this is adding fresh markup)

when you run refresh() it will only update the data you just added and skip exsiting data.

Comment: I understood that much, but how do I go about updating an existing data node? (without creating the exact same node with a the different markup)